# sql developer does not start

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have come across a rather weird scenario, not sure if anyone has seen it.
I have a sql developer version 3.xx installed and working properly for years until this morning.... when I tried to export a view of 300K+ records to an excel file. I then left sql developer but when I came back in, I can no longer start the application. No error but nothing happened. I went into sqldeveloper folder inside the application and started the application using cmd.com and this is the error (not sure if I am supposed to run it from command prompt though)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin>sqldeveloper
java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: com.sun.java.accessibility.Ac
cessBridge
        at java.awt.Toolkit.loadAssistiveTechnologies(Toolkit.java:773)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:872)
        at java.awt.Window.getToolkit(Window.java:1174)
        at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:396)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:434)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:202)
        at oracle.ide.IdeCore$StartupWindow.<init>(IdeCore.java:1960)
        at oracle.ide.IdeCore.startupImpl(IdeCore.java:1148)
        at oracle.ide.Ide.startup(Ide.java:703)
        at oracle.ideimpl.DefaultIdeStarter.startIde(DefaultIdeStarter.java:35)
        at oracle.ideimpl.Main.start(Main.java:184)
        at oracle.ideimpl.Main.main(Main.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at oracle.ide.boot.PCLMain.callMain(PCLMain.java:62)
        at oracle.ide.boot.PCLMain.main(PCLMain.java:54)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at oracle.classloader.util.MainClass.invoke(MainClass.java:128)
        at oracle.ide.boot.IdeLauncher.bootClassLoadersAndMain(IdeLauncher.java:
189)
        at oracle.ide.boot.IdeLauncher.launchImpl(IdeLauncher.java:89)
        at oracle.ide.boot.IdeLauncher.launch(IdeLauncher.java:65)
        at oracle.ide.boot.IdeLauncher.main(IdeLauncher.java:54)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at oracle.ide.boot.Launcher.invokeMain(Launcher.java:713)
        at oracle.ide.boot.Launcher.launchImpl(Launcher.java:115)
        at oracle.ide.boot.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:68)
        at oracle.ide.boot.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:57)
```

Does someone have an idea of what was going on? I have tried to delete and get another copy of sqldeveloper from the Oracle site, but the situation has not improved. Is there something that I have overlooked? I believe the export did something to the application but I am not smart enough to figure out what. Your hints are highly appreciated!

Comment: I still do not know what was wrong with my sql developer application but when I used the newest version of java sdk (not certified), the application works again. The application complaints that the results may not correct since java sdk is uncertified but oh well....

Comment: in case someone comes across this again, this looks sound https://askubuntu.com/questions/695560/assistive-technology-not-found-awterror

Answer (score 0):

try running the batch file to start it

It's probably in the same folder as the sqldeveloper.exe. It may be a Java level mismatch in which case you will be warned and asked if you want to proceed, or you can install a compatible version.